# How to manually run a windows service periodically

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-services

I have a windows service that runs every 30 minutes on a server.  My boss wants me to add a button in the admin section of the application that runs the service and retrieves current information. This is current code for the service....

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    _stop.Reset();
    //30 minutes = 1800000
    //5 minutes = 300000
    //1 minute = 60000
    _registeredWait = ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(_stop,
        new WaitOrTimerCallback(PeriodicProcess), null, 1800000, false);
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
    _stop.Set();
}

private void PeriodicProcess(object state, bool timeout)
{
    if (timeout)
    {
        // Periodic processing here
    }
    else
    {
        // Stop any more events coming along
        _registeredWait.Unregister(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Well thanks for letting us know ... did you have a question you needed answered?

Comment: If you want to manually start the service check [ServiceController.Start](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yb9w7ytd(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: My question is how do I get the windows service to  start if it isn't already running and in waiting state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to start a service that isn't running using [ServiceController](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
using (var sc = new ServiceController("NameOfYourService", "NameOfYourServer"))
    sc.Start();
```